# AnimationView not appearing when called

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I'm using the Lottie API to have a custom Animation View in one of my static table view cells using the below code. However, the view is not appearing.

I have tested other Lottie files, therefore it is not the file. And I have also tested the cell by changing its `backgroundColor`, which worked, so I am calling the right cell.

```
let index = IndexPath(row: 9, section: 0)

let cellWidth = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: index)?.frame.size.width
let cellHeight = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: index)?.frame.size.height

let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "loader1")
self.animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellWidth! / 2, height: 50)
self.animationView.center = (self.tableView.cellForRow(at: index)?.center)!
self.animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
self.animationView.loopAnimation = true

self.tableView.cellForRow(at: index)?.addSubview(self.animationView)

self.animationView.play()
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the subview to the self.tableView.cellForRow(at: index)?.contentView - i.e. not directly to the cell?

Comment: @andym Just tried that now, and it didn't work

Comment: Try setting cellWidth and cellHeight using the contentView too. Also comment out the self.animationView.center row too.

Comment: @andym Perfect, that fixed it!